# Error when running Mocha tests with mochaphantom js in a Durandal environment

Tags: requirejs, mocha.js, durandal, mocha-phantomjs

I have a problem including mocha tests in a durandal environment. I want to run my tests with mocha-phantomjs from the command line. The test works perfectly in the browser but as soon as I'm trying to use mocha-phantomjs I'm getting the following error message (command: mocha-phantomjs dummyPage.htm):

```
Error: Your custom reporter tried to require 'fs', but Mocha is not running in N
ode.js in mocha-phantomjs, so Node modules cannot be required - only other repor
ters
```

My dummmy html page looks like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '../app/',
        paths: {
            'app': '../app',
            'specs': '../sampleTest/specs/',
            'text': '../lib/require/text',
            'durandal': '../lib/durandal/js',
            'plugins' : '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
            'transitions' : '/lib/durandal/js/transitions',
            'knockout': '../lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0',
            'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1'
        }
    });
    var runTests = function (specfiles) {
        // Initialize mocha and leak assert into the global space.
        mocha.setup('bdd');
        mocha.reporter('html');
        assert = chai.assert;
        require(specfiles, function () {
            require(['specs/test.spec'],function(spec){
                    if (window.mochaPhantomJS) {
                        console.log('test with phantomJS')
                        mochaPhantomJS.run();
                    }
                    else {
                        mocha.run();
                    }
                });
        });
    };
    runTests();
</script>
```

and my sample test looks like that:

```
define(['viewmodels/flickr'], function (flickr) {
    describe('Flickr-Test', function(){
        it('displayName should be equal to Flickr', function () {
            assert.equal(flickr.displayName,'Flickr','should load right view model');
        });
        it('state should be pending', function () {
            assert.equal(flickr.activate().state(),'pending','state should be pending');
        });
    });
    describe("DOM Test", function () {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.id = "myDiv";
    el.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    var myEl = document.getElementById('myDiv');

    it("has the right text", function () {
        assert.equal(myEl.innerHTML,'Hello World!')
    });
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with mocha-phantomjs, but you might be hit by an issue that is described in http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Native-Apps-With-Node-Webkit.html

> Next, because node has it's own implementation of require that is
>   different from require.js, which Durandal uses, we need to patch
>   things up a bit. To do that, add the following script block to the
>   head of your index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// this doesn't apply when not running with node webkit (nw)
// window.gui = require('nw.gui');

  window.requireNode = window.require;
  delete window.require;

  window.requireNode.version = process.versions.node;
  delete process.versions.node;
</script>
```

Comment: When I put that section into the header I'm getting the following error: 

Error: Module name "nw.gui" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

Comment: Code above was the quoted solution for node webkit. I've updated the code sample.